# Notification Service in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, client-server

I am going to design a notification service which is supposed to do the following:

- Clients call notification service at startup with initial data (client ip, client id).
- The server saves clients in connected clients list using their IPs.
- If one client needs to notify (send message to) other clients, it calls a method on the notification service to publish this message to other clients using their IPs.
- On client shutdown, the service removes this client from connected clients list.

**My Question is:**

1- Is this an applicable design for such a notification service?

2- I know that connections between service and client can be implemented using WCF callbacks, Microsoft Message Queue and Sockets. Is there any other technology / method that can be used in c#?

**Note:**

Now, clients are .net c# applications, but in the future clients may contain mobile applications, so i need a method that is platform independent.

Thank you

Comment: You should take alook at SignalIR http://signalr.net/

Comment: It is not only web, Here is a sample for WPF and Windows Forms app: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Using-SignalR-in-WinForms-f1ec847b

Comment: You're going to have to provide a lot more information on your requirement to get a useful answer. What are your throughput/scalability requirements? How many clients will you have connected at the same time? How big are notification messages? Is this for a local enterprise network where you have lots of control over the topology, or over public internet?

Comment: total clients count is 200, maybe 100 clients will connect at the same time. notification messages are simple string messages, using a local network